# Determining Connections between data in a single table

Tags: sql, analysis

I'm a BA / programmer type doing data analysis on a legacy system. I've been teaching myself SQL to help, but I've appeared to hit upon a problem bigger than my abilities.

I have two tables (generalized for simplicity):

**Table Objects**

```
Object_PK
```

**Table Components**

```
Component_PK
Object_FK
Component_Type
```

There are 100+ distinct values in Component_Type_Code. Given that any object can have N number of Components, how can I see which Component_Type(s) appear with other Component_Type(s)?

For example, the following query tells me what component_types appear with the component_type 'Component_type_1':

```
select component_type_code, count(*)
from components
where object_fk in (
        select object_fk
        from components
        where component_type_code = 'component_type_1'
)
group by component_type_code
```

I'd like to get a query to show me all connections

My apologies for the formatting. Any help is appreciated. I've looked at cube and rollup, but didn't know how to apply to this situation.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Output would be something similar to :  
Component_Type_Code   Component_Type_Code   Count    
Code1                 Code2                 5  
Code1                 Code3                 10 
Code2                 Code3                 7  
  
This output shows that column1 code appears in objects that also have column2 code count(*) times.

Comment: Honestly, I can't even figure out how to properly format on stackoverflow. Help says to end each line with two spaces '  ' to initiate a line break. I've got major issues and it might be a ID 10 T error, or something similar (EBKAC)

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly you want to see every Component_Type which occurs more than once in each component. Therefore;

```
SELECT component_type_code, COUNT(*)
FROM components
WHERE object_fk IN(
        SELECT object_fk
        FROM components
        GROUP BY component_type_code
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

**EDIT**

Considering the complexity of your requirements it will be difficult to align that all into one statement.

Therefore, you have the code which is working for one component_type, so I would insert that data into a temporary table and then repeat for each other component_type. Finally;

SELECT *
FROM #TempComponents

I realise this isn't ideal, and no doubt you might want to add new component_type, but it will work.

Comment: Not exactly, but we are getting there. I want to see the relation between component types. So how many times Component_type_1 appears in all objects with component_type_2, for all component_types. So in the end I would have a report that says:

Component_type    appears with     component_type     count(*)
Component_type1                    Component_typ2     5
Component_type1                    Componenet_type3   100
etc...

*fingers crossed formatting works*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the good answers. I had also e-mailed the question out to a few DBA friends, and one of them responded with the following SQL:

```
 Select a.Component_Type, b.Component_Type, count(1)
 From Components a, Components b
 Where b.Object_FK = a.Object_FK
 And b.Component_Type > a.Component_Type
 Group By a.Component_Type, b.Component_Type
```

This statement returns the associated links and their count. Its actually really cool analysis and I wish I didn't have to generalize the tables and result. Thanks to everyone - I hope this SQL is useful to someone in the future!